# How do I split a list of tuples into two lists in haskell using the map function?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, unzip

This is for homework due yesterday but I do not want the answer just a point to the right direction please;)

I am trying to implement the `unzip` function using `map` and lambda with haskell.

```
:t unzip
[(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
```

and so I am thinking that the lambda would look like `\(a,b)->([a],[b])` and that sort of works except I am getting from my input of `[(4,5),(7,5),(9,7)] =>
[([4],[5]),([7],[5]),([9],[7])]` but I would have liked to have seen `[4,7,9],[5,5,7]`. So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])` returns a list, right? And you want your function to return two lists, so... you'll need to use `map` twice. Here's a skeleton for you to fill in:

```
unzip xs = (map {- ??? -} xs, map {- ??? -} xs)
```

Unfortunately, insisting on using `map` is inefficient, because it means you must make two passes over the list. You can do a bit better, but it's tricky! Give it a shot, then see how well you did by comparing it with [GHC's implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#unzip).

Answer (score 4):

you can not implement `unzip` in a single map

```
\(a,b)->([a],[b]) :: (a,b) -> ([a],[b])
```

so

```
map \(a,b)->([a],[b]) :: [(a,b)] -> [([a],[b])]
```

instead you need *two* maps

```
unzip ls = (map ???,map ???)
```

fill in the blanks